# Problema usando listas de vogais e números pares

Tags: python, array, lista

O exercício é o seguinte:

> Faça um programa em que o usuário digite uma letra e um número
>   inteiro. Caso a letra seja vogal e o número for par, ou a letra for
>   consoante e o número ímpar, mostre “BAZINGA!”. Caso contrário, mostre
>   “SHAZAM!”.

Eu fiz dessa maneira:

```
vogal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
par = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
letra = input("Entre com a letra: ")
numero = input("Entre com o numero: ")
if letra in vogal and numero in par:
    print("Bazinga!")
elif letra not in vogal and numero in par:
    print("Shazam!")
else:
    print("Bazinga!")
```

Porém, quando executo esse código, mesmo se eu entrar com "b" e "2", a saída vai sair Bazinga, sendo que como consta no exercício deveria ser "Shazam" a saída. O que tem de errado em meu código? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, o erro aí foi que você não declarou o input como inteiro `int()`, aí a comparação sempre dava errada, pois estava comparando `'2'`(str) com `2`(int)

Outra coisa que eu alterei foi na hora de checar se o número é par ou impar, usando `%` você pode fazer isso facilmente, se `numero % 2` retornar zero é par, se não, impar.

Espero ter ajudado.

**Ficando assim:**

```
vogal = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
letra = input("Entre com a letra: ")
numero = int(input("Entre com o numero: ")) # Agora que está com int() está correto.
if (letra in vogal and numero % 2 == 0) or (letra not in vogal and numero % 2 != 0): #Uma forma melhor de checar se é ou não par.
    print("Bazinga!")
else:
    print("Shazam!")
```